# Nesting nuget packages

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, nuget

I have a nuget package containing retry policies and a number of nuget packages for 
database , http and cache clients. The idea is that all external depedencies should be accessed in an ordered and safe way. All packages are hosted in a private nuget server.

If I include the retry policy nuget package into the individual clients' nuget package, would be great on one hand because the end application using only one package will get the full functionality.

On the other hand, an update in the base package (retry policy in this examples case) would trigger a massive need for updates in many other nuget packages, used by several applications.

Is there any established best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal practice is to keep the nugets as independant as possible. So the less dependecies the better.

If your client nuget code depends on it (as it does not compile without it) you have to add it anyway.

If your client nugets code don't diectly depend on the retry policies than you are better of don't adding it as dependency.

This keeps you flexible enough in the future for using differrent retry policies when the client nugets are used.

As you already expect: If you add it and you have to update your retry policy nuget you will have to update the client nugets too for just using a different version of the dependency (though no actual code has been changed).

For bundling a set of nugets with specified versions (as i think you want) you can still create meta packages/nugets which just hold the selected dependencies and no code.